# Leave a team in Trello

Tags: trello

I've created a team and a board in Trello, but I no longer want to belong to it. Is it possible to leave the team and the board without deleting the board and give it to a member of the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave a board in Trello, open the board menu on the right side of the board, click "More" and choose "Leave Board". This will remove your user from the board, which means you may no longer be able to access the board.

reference: http://help.trello.com/article/804-leaving-a-board-in-trello

Trello won't let you leave a board if you're the only admin or member of that board. Presumably, someone needs to be in control of the board. If this happens, and you still want to leave the board, you can make the user named 'trello' an admin of that board and then leave the board. 'trello' is a demo user we created for the Welcome Board and is not used by an actual human.

Comment: The board data ... remains available for members who remains on the board?

Comment: Trello won't let you leave a board if you're the only admin or member of that board. Presumably, someone needs to be in control of the board. If this happens, and you still want to leave the board, you can make the user named 'trello' an admin of that board and then leave the board. 'trello' is a demo user we created for the Welcome Board and is not used by an actual human.

Comment: Please add your last comment to the answer and I mark it as the answer. Thanks!